# Trees l'asid lavo

Tags: food, sources-mekorot, trees, latid-lavo-future

I recall learning that la'asid lavo the trees themselves will be edible (ta'm ha'etz k'tam hapri) as in gan eden. I cannot find the source for this though.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that they will be edible in addition to having the same flavor?

Comment: +0, since the question contains too many Hebrew words and too few English words.  Please dejargonify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source for *this* is **[Torath Kohanim 26:5](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%90_%28%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%99%22%D7%9D%29_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%97%D7%A7%D7%AA%D7%99_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%90)**

> [ה] מנין שהעץ עתיד להיות נאכל? תלמוד לומר "עץ פרי"; אם ללמד שהוא עושה
>   פרי, והלא כבר נאמר "עושה פרי"!? אם כן למה נאמר "עץ פרי"? אלא מה פרי
>   נאכל, אף העץ נאכל.

---

BTW, I think that your statement "as in Gan eden" is incorrect.

Rashi on [Bereshit 1:11](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8165/showrashi/true) clearly states that the trees didn't do like Hashem commanded
(ie that the trees themselves would be edible like fruit)

> עץ פרי: **שיהא טעם העץ כטעם הפרי, והיא לא עשתה כן**, אלא (פסוק יב) ותוצא
>   הארץ עץ *עושה* פרי, **ולא העץ פרי**, לפיכך כשנתקלל אדם על עונו נפקדה גם היא
>   על עונה ונתקללה:
>
> fruit trees: That the taste of the tree should be like the taste of
>   the fruit. It [the earth] did not do so, however, but “the earth gave
>   forth, etc., trees producing fruit,” **but the trees themselves were not fruit**.

====================

**PS:** (just while we're on this topic:)

The same Torath Kohanim 26:5 goes on to say that L'Atid Lavo **non-fruit bearing trees will give fruit**.

See [Vayikra 26:4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9927/showrashi/true)

> ד. וְנָתַתִּי גִשְׁמֵיכֶם בְּעִתָּם וְנָתְנָה הָאָרֶץ יְבוּלָהּ וְעֵץ
>   הַשָּׂדֶה יִתֵּן פִּרְיוֹ
>
> . I will give your rains in their time, the Land will yield its
>   produce, and the tree of the field will give forth its fruit.

Rashi:

> ועץ השדה: הן אילני סרק, ועתידין לעשות פירות:
>
> the tree of the field: This refers to trees [planted in the field, as opposed to the orchard,] that do not bear fruit, but are destined to bear fruit in the future. — [**Torath Kohanim 26:5**]

See also the end of Masechet Ktuvot. [112b]

> אמר רב חייא בר אשי אמר רב עתידין כל אילני סרק שבארץ ישראל שיטענו פירות
>   שנאמר (יואל ב, כב) כי עץ נשא פריו תאנה וגפן נתנו חילם:

Comment: Well, so much for the book I just brought up to my computer desk. :-)